# When computing period-specific hazard ratio using Cox, should I add variable:strata or full variable * strata?

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, stratification, proportional-hazards

Let's asusme I want to calculate separate hazards ratio in two periods, split like below.

```r
lung.split <- survSplit(Surv(time, status) ~ ., data= lung, 
                 cut=c(180, 350), episode= "tgroup", id="id")
head(lung.split[-c(1,4,6:8)])
  age sex ph.karno id tstart time status tgroup
1  74   1       90  1      0  180      0      1
2  74   1       90  1    180  306      1      2
3  68   1       90  2      0  180      0      1
4  68   1       90  2    180  350      0      2
5  68   1       90  2    350  455      1      3
6  56   1       90  3      0  180      0      1
```

In the model, should I specify the ph.karno interaction with strata(tgroup) or the full intersection ph.karno*strata(tgroup)?

```r
coef(summary(coxph(Surv(tstart, time, status) ~ 
       ph.karno:strata(tgroup), data=lung.split) ))
                                       coef exp(coef)    se(coef)           z     Pr(>|z|)
ph.karno:strata(tgroup)tgroup=1 -0.03705078 0.9636272 0.009639277 -3.84373017 0.0001211782
ph.karno:strata(tgroup)tgroup=2 -0.01235100 0.9877250 0.011203220 -1.10245080 0.2702657352
ph.karno:strata(tgroup)tgroup=3  0.00062297 1.0006232 0.010267832  0.06067201 0.9516204222
```

vs

```r
coef(summary(coxph(Surv(tstart, time, status) ~ 
       ph.karno*strata(tgroup), data=lung.split) ))
                                       coef exp(coef)    se(coef)         z     Pr(>|z|)
ph.karno                        -0.03705078 0.9636272 0.009639277 -3.843730 0.0001211782
ph.karno:strata(tgroup)tgroup=2  0.02469978 1.0250073 0.014779303  1.671241 0.0946740453
ph.karno:strata(tgroup)tgroup=3  0.03767375 1.0383924 0.014083466  2.675034 0.0074721710
```

The HRs are very close, but the p-values are very different!

What exactly the two models specify?

I understand the second one compares the HRs towards the first one (the reference), so that's why they don't differ from each other (high p-value).

But what does the first one with only the ph.karno:strata(tgroup)? Why the last one was 0.95 for one approach and 0.007 for the second one? Maybe in this case we compare the coefficients itself against zero? This would make a bit more sense. Are they the period-specific log-rank tests, like in an ordinary Cox with 1 categorical covariate?

I'm using the default `contr.treatment` contrast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a matter of how the results are displayed. If you remove `coef()` from your 2 function calls, you will see that the 2 models are identical in terms of concordance and the likelihood-ratio, score, and Wald tests.

In the first model, the results are displayed in absolute terms within each stratum.

In the second model, `tgroup = 1` is treated as a reference group, and its `ph.karno` coefficient of `-0.037051` is the same as in the first model. The other coefficients, however, are reported as *differences from* that reference  coefficient, as is standard for the default treatment coding used in R. For example, for `tgroup = 2` in the second model, `-0.037051 + 0.024700 = -0.012351`, the  `tgroup = 2` coefficient in the first model.

In this particular case the first models is easier to interpret directly, but the models are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes perfect sense. I should have look at it more carefully. I am sorry for asking for too much, but I have a related question here, could you, please, look at it too?
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574407/how-do-i-use-the-survdiff-in-a-sequence-of-subsequent-periods-cox-with-strata